# dotlesscss is not wotking with bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, iis-6, dotless

Anyone else ran on this problem? I installed dotlesscss on server. And then bootstrap less files. Now I get error from /bootstrap.less

```
Expected ')' but found ' ' on line 47 in file 'mixins.less':
 [46]: // Sizing shortcuts
 [47]: .size(@width; @height) {
       ------------^
 [48]:   width: @width;
```

I googled and found that it seems to be some sort of bug.

How should I use less on my project if dotlesscss is not working? What other server side solutions? Some easy approach would be nice...